# Cannot access on premises Jenkins from Azure

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I want to be able to create a pull request from Azure that will kick off my Jenkins build machine. I normally access the Jenkins server over VPN. And the Azure instance is in the cloud. I have followed the steps in Service Hooks to add a Subscription, but after adding the on premises "Jenkins base URL", User Name, and API Token, the Build field fails to fill in with the error "Jenkins query fail with exception 'The remote name cannot be resolved: <Internal_Server_Name>'. How do I go about exposing the Jenkins machine so that Azure can see it? This would then allow for the builds to be filled in so I can select the correct one.

[image]

I've seen a bunch of Azure plugins for Jenkins, but am confused about what the right choice is.

Thx for the help :)

Comment: So what's the exact question? If the Jenkins is unavailable to the web and/or your PC without connecting to the VPN, then the dropdowns don't work. But if you enter the correct values manually, an agent on the same network as the jenkins instance should be able to pass the job onward without issues.

Comment: Forgot an important point, the Azure intense is hosted in the cloud, so it is no on premises. So how do I go about accessing from the cloud to on prem instance?

Comment: You may need to make sure the Jenkins instance is reachable from a public address or setup ExpressRoute: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/expressroute-for-azure-devops/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a pipeline and then add a `Jenkins queue job` task to the pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Then you can set [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) in the branch policy to make the build pipeline triggered by pull request. With this setting, once you initiate a PR on the target branch, the Build validation will trigger the build pipeline that you set, only after the build is successful, the PR will be allowed to complete.